# Why we need copy object of useState to make change to UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two component , child and parent component

In parent component, it have hook to pass to child, like this

```
const dayOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tus", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
const status = [false, false, false, true, false, false, false]
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(status)
```

And i use that in child component by

```
      <View row style={{ flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
            {dayOfWeek.map((item, index) => (
              <View>
                {console.log("this will re-render")}
                <DateItem
                  key={index}
                  days={item}
                  selected={selected}
                  setSelected={setSelected}
                  index={index}
                />
         </View>
            ))}
```

And i have child component, like this

```
const DateItem = (props: DateItemProps) => {
  const { days, selected, setSelected, index } = props

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      row
      center
      onPress={() => {
        selected[index] = !selected[index]

        setSelected(selected)
        console.log("selected", selected)
      }}
      style={!selected[index] ? CONTAINER_WITHOUT_SELECTED : CONTAINER_WITH_SELECTED}
    >
      <Text style={!selected[index] ? TEXT_WITHOUT_SELECTED : TEXT_WITH_SELECTED}>{days}</Text>
      {selected[index] && <Icon name="check" color="white" />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
```

But, i wonder why i need to copy new array to change state of hook, like this

```
const DateItem = (props: DateItemProps) => {
  const { days, selected, setSelected, index } = props

  let updateArray = [...selected]
  console.log("outside", updateArray)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      row
      center
      onPress={() => {
        updateArray[index] = !updateArray[index]
        setSelected(updateArray)
    
      }}
      style={!updateArray[index] ? CONTAINER_WITHOUT_SELECTED : CONTAINER_WITH_SELECTED}
    >
      <Text style={!updateArray[index] ? TEXT_WITHOUT_SELECTED : TEXT_WITH_SELECTED}>{days}</Text>
      {updateArray[index] && <Icon name="check" color="white" />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

If i use `updateArray`, the UI change immediately , but if i use hook value, in here is `selected`, they update in log, i logged in `onPress` of touchableOpacity but not update in UI, if i restart, UI update like expected

[image]

Show i wonder **why we need create clone and apply to hook for update UI??**

I thought it because parent component re-render, but after i apply `key` ,they do not re-render, so what happen to child componet, why they do not update the UI if i update the array , here is `selected` and i must copy array (`updateArray`) to get UI update?

Comment: React cannot detect that the state changed unless you pass a new array to the setter function. If you change the old array in place, then `oldState === newState` and React has no clue that you did anything to the array at all.

Comment: So i understand is, react check where state was pointed in memory, not it value, is that right? And if i change value, restart, it point to new memory, then it show as expected, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the memory reference needs to change. Otherwise React would have to walk through the entire state (and all children, etc) and compare each value.

Comment: But why for exmple, if i use `const [state,setstate]= useState(0)` , then i do `setState(state+1)` , it still update?  Is because i use primitive variable?? If that right, do react compare directly primitive variable?

Comment: Exactly, and you still aren't modifying the variable in place. `state+1` is a new integer. https://jsfiddle.net/ympe69df/